# Accessing specific server choice root directory in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been provided with signing in credentials into phpMyAdmin by my organisation's admin i.e. a server choice, username and password. I'm working through the following chapter "15- Using PHP to Access MySQL" of [this](http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training/119003-2.html) course and my objective is to utilise the provided credentials to upload the following PHP scripts in order to test the below PHP scripts. The second script is the important script for me as I need to test if I can connect to the database created in the server choice by my admin:

See code below for my helloworld.php script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Testing 123 ... Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

See code below for my databases.php script:

```
    <?php 
  // 1.Create a database connection
  $dbhost = "mydbhostserver";
  $dbuser = "uname";
  $dbpass = "password";
  $dbname = "dbname";

  $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

  // Test if connection occured
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
      mysqli_connect_error() . 
      "(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Connecting to MySQL with PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

<?php 
  // 5.Close a database connection
  mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

In mentioning the above my question/issue is how in phpMyAdmin do I go about accessing the web server's root directory i.e. (DOCUMENT_ROOT) as I understand it from this page to upload my above script (and other scripts)?

Not to sound trivial but is this something I can access using one of the tabbed options in phpMyAdmin i.e. Databases, SQL, status, etc ... or is this

My second issue is how in phpMyAdmin can I be certain that my server is PHP enabled? Once I sign in on the landing page under the summary of bullet points titled web server I can see this "PHP extension: mysqli". Does this indicate the server choice I was assigned to sign into is PHP enabled?

I appreciate any suggestions/pointers.

Comment: Hi guys, does anyone have any suggestions regarding my above post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this usage, you won't use phpMyAdmin at all. phpMyAdmin is a tool to administrate MySQL databases, and it happens to be written in the PHP programming language.

What you're trying to do is upload a PHP script to your webserver, which is done outside of phpMyAdmin (generally using something like FTP, SFTP or SCP). Since phpMyAdmin is designed to manage database instances, there's no feature to upload PHP files through it. Also, the fact that phpMyAdmin works on your server is a good indicator that your PHP installation works correctly. The specific line you mention "PHP extension: mysqli" refers to the function library configured for phpMyAdmin to use (through PHP) to access the MySQL server. Your code also appears to be using the mysqli library.

Comment: @ Isaac Bentech: Thanks for advice as it has proved valuable. Using cyberduck for mac I've been able to upload PHP file containing the above code in a new folder in the web server root directory.